# T-SQL Init several variables from table's row with single select

Tags: t-sql, variables, sql-server-2012, initialization

I have the following table (let's say that its name is "AnswerTable":

```
QuestionID Value
100        1
101        2
102        1
103        2
104        1
105        2
...
```

Then I have several variables:

```
DECLARE @Answer1 INT
DECLARE @Answer2 INT
....
```

and I need to retrieve information from the table like this:

```
SET @Answer1 =(SELECT Value FROM AnswerTable WHERE QuestionID=100)
SET @Answer2 =(SELECT Value FROM AnswerTable WHERE QuestionID=101)
...
```

And what I want to do is to initialize the variables with only one select from the table, because in my real situation the table is very big and it is joined with other tables and I am concerned that multiple execution of the sub query is not going to be efficient.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Part of me is thinking that there is probably a better way to do this than dump all the answers in a bunch of variables then do something with them later. What is the bigger picture? What are you going to use all those @AnswerX variables for?

Comment: I am going to use the code in store procedure - after variables initializing and checking if they are in the correct format they will be inserted in other table, generally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In General;

```
SELECT @Answer1 = col1, @Answer2 = col2, ... FROM yourTable
```

In Your case;

```
SELECT @Answer1 = case QuestionID when 100 then Value Else @Answer1 End, 
       @Answer2 = case QuestionID when 101 then Value Else @Answer2 End
FROM AnswerTable
WHERE QuestionID IN  (100,101)
```

**Ex:** [Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6713c/1)

Comment: +1 Тhanks a lot, this works perfectly. I've knew that the case/when statements are the answers, but did not know what to do when the Question ID does not matched. So, returning the current variable on the else clause is very nice idea.

Comment: @gotqn : No problems, here is a [Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6713c/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, but I've tested it with my real data before accepting your answer :P

Answer (score 0):

It's a little awkward but you can use joins to do this.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3fe7/4

```
DECLARE @Answer1 INT
DECLARE @Answer2 INT

SELECT 
  @Answer1 = Question100.Value, 
  @Answer2 = Question101.Value 
FROM 
  AnswerTable AS Question100 
INNER JOIN AnswerTable AS Question101 
  ON Question101.QuestionId = 101 
WHERE Question100.QuestionID=100


select @Answer1, @Answer2
```

Comment: @Answer2 needs to be populated from the row where QuestionID = 101, not 100

Comment: @ColinMackay Thanks, I missed that.